# Issue getting only session data from MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am attempting to perform a MySQL query in which it selects data only from what the user has created during that session. For example, the user records a number of activity sessions and when the `coast.php` file is executed, it displays only the sessions the logged in user has recorded for that session in the PDF output.

I have so far managed to get the query working to some degree, but it is still selecting everything from the database and I cannot figure out how to do this correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code so far...

**coast.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('../tcpdf/examples/lang/eng.php');
require_once('../tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Ash Williams');
$pdf->SetTitle('Coastline Coasteer Invoice');
$pdf->SetSubject('ASHLEY');
$pdf->SetKeywords('wILLIAMS');
// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData("ibill logo.png", PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, '', 
'');
//Set header margin
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
//set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(12, 35, 12, true);
//set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
//set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
//set some language-dependent strings
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
// ---------------------------------------------------------
// set default font subsetting mode
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);
// Set font
// dejavusans is a UTF-8 Unicode font, if you only need to
// print standard ASCII chars, you can use core fonts like
// helvetica or times to reduce file size.
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 12, '', true);
// Add a page
// This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
$pdf->AddPage();
// Set some content to print
$html = '<style>
            h1 {
                letter-spacing: 1px;
                 font-family: times;
                 font-size: 30px;
                 text-align: center;
                 text-transform: uppercase;
                 text-decoration:underline;
            }
            h2 {
                font-weight: normal;
                text-align: left;
            }
        </style>
                <h1>Invoice</h1>
                <h2>Coastline Coasteer</h2>

                <h3>22 Headland Road,</h3>

                <h3>Newquay, Cornwall</h3>
                <h3>TR7 1HN</h3>
                <h3>Tel: 01637 879571</h3>';

$tbl_header = '<table border="1" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="4" nobr="true">';
$tbl_footer = '</table>';
$tbl ='';
$tbl .= '
          <tr>
            <th style="border: 3px solid black";>Type of Activity</th>
            <th style="border: 3px solid black";>Employer</th>
            <th style="border: 3px solid black";>Date</th>
            <th style="border: 3px solid black";>Time</th>
            <th style="border: 3px solid black";>Amount (GBP)</th>
          </tr>
        ';
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","****","****");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$tusername=$_SESSION["user_session"];
$queryString = "SELECT * FROM session_details, users WHERE employer = 'Coastline Coasteer' AND username = '" .$tusername. "';"; 
//print $queryString;
$result = mysqli_query($con,$queryString);
//if (!$result) {
//  print 'failed';
//}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $typeofactivity = $row['typeofactivity'];
  $employer = $row['employer'];
  $date = $row['date'];
  $time = $row['amount'];
  $tbl .= '<tr>
            <td>'.$row["typeofactivity"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["employer"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["date"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["time"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["amount"].'</td>
          </tr>';
}
// Print text using writeHTMLCell()
$pdf->writeHTML($html . $tbl_header . $tbl . $tbl_footer, true, false, false, false, '');
// ---------------------------------------------------------
// Close and output PDF document
// This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
$pdf->Output('coastline_invoice.pdf', 'D');
//============================================================+
// END OF FILE
//============================================================+
?>
```

Comment: You have //print $queryString; commented out in your code.  Run that, and execute the SQL in your database and try getting it working there, most of what you have listed here isn't meaningful for solving the problem.  We'd need to see how records are being inserted into your DB or the DB tables themselves.  Good luck!

Comment: Hi @DaOgre, I have commented out the print as my TCPDF class doesn't run with it. I have inserted the query into my DB and it displays all of the values in the DB with 'Coastline Coasteer' in them. Thanks for the pointer

Comment: You could add it to the $pdf->writeHTML($html . $tbl_header . $tbl . $tbl_footer . $queryString); if you want to view it.  I would imagine information isn't properly being saved into user_session so you've just got a blank value there, but you'll need to actually look at the values in the DB to confirm that.

Comment: okay thanks, yes just blank values. I only have two tables. `users` which stores user details and `session_details` which stores the session values. Would it help if i showed my table structure here?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you do have neither implicit, nor explicit join condition between session_details and users tables. The `session_details, users` syntax without any join condition will create a carthesian join between the 2 tables, meaning every record from session_details table is matched to every single record in users table.

You have to define a join condition between the 2 tables, something along these lines:

```
SELECT *
FROM session_details sd
INNER JOIN users u ON sd.user_id=u.user_id
WHERE employer = 'Coastline Coasteer' AND username = '...'
```

I just made up the field names in the join expression, but the point is, in the session_details table should be associated with the user table in some way through a common field. You need to determine what this field is (or these fields are) to match the appropriate records from the 2 tables with each other.

Comment: Thanks @Shadow, i have an id column in both tables. I just attempted linking them as per your query in mysql but it is still returning blank values.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot comment on why your query displays blank data if I do not see your data. Pls provide sample data for both tables, the exact query you tried, the results retirned by your query, and the expected results. However, you should not expect us to figure out on which field(s) your tables can be linked. That's up to you to determine!

Comment: I understand that and appreciate your help! example data for session_details: id=1, typeofactivity=coasteer, employer=coastline coasteer, date=2016-04-11, time=12:00:00 example data for users: id=1, username=nametest password=password, firstname=name, surname=test email=name@test.com

Comment: Query tried: SELECT * FROM session_details sd INNER JOIN users u ON sd.id=u.id WHERE employer = 'Coastline Coasteer' AND username = ' nametest'

Comment: query result:  MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0025 seconds.)

Comment: Expected results: To display only the sessions that were stored in that particular session from whichever user is logged in and not the entire session_details table

Comment: I do not see a direct connection between the 2 tables, to be honest. The id fields have the same name, but I do not think that they relate to the same stuff. They seem to be the ids for their respective table only. I think you should have a 3rd table somewhere that connect these 2 tables. Your query may not return any results on your sample data because in your sample data all characters are lowercase, while in your query the search string contains upper case letters as well. The best would be to create an sqlfiddle for us (sqlfiddle.com) with proper sample data.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have here is that your session isn't saving any information.  In the line:

```
$tusername=$_SESSION["user_session"];
```

You're referring to the value user_session which doesn't appear to be set anywhere on this page.  You can try printing out the $_SESSION variable with `print_r($_SESSION)`. $_SESSION is just an array however, and so unless you store some value in here, you're just referring to a blank value, and as such when you're running your actual query, you're querying for a blank value.

You can demonstrate this with a new test php page which just has the following:

```
<?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Your output will be: Array()

Comment: i have this stored in my loginform.php which starts the log in session: $_SESSION["user_session"]=$username; Do i need it in this page also?

Comment: this gets the username on input from the login form

Comment: Session data may be set in other php pages, that's the whole purpose of the session: to persist data between calls.

Comment: @asharoo85 no, do not try to set the user_session in this code, if it is not populated here.